# SwiftUI: How to have a a new view show every day based on the date with previous views lasting a week

Tags: foreach, swiftui

So honestly, I'm stuck. I'm trying to make something similar to the App Store, where there is a 'Today' view that contains things from the current date. Under that, I want the last 6 days to show. I've figured out how to make a new view appear every day with the past week, as long as the past week is in the same month. I can't figure out how to make it work once a new month comes, as the way I'm doing it is by using the current date, subtracting 6 days, then getting a range between those two days. It breaks once the new month comes, as the range changes from looking like 12...18 to 30...5, which breaks it! That being said, it's a little more complex than that. the View that I am trying to iterate has 3 inputs- a year, a month, and a day. The day is what I've been using the range to iterate on. Here is my code:

// HomeView //

```
struct HomeView: View{
    
    let future = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 25), to: Date())!
    
    let aWeekAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -6), to: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 28), to: Date())!)!
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                ForEach((dayRange).reversed(), id: \.self) { i in
                    CardView(day: yearData[0].months[0].dayInfo[i])
                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 40)
        }
    }
}
```

// HomeView extension //

```
extension HomeView {
    
    var dayRange: Range<Int> {
        let day = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: future)
        let dayAWeekago = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: aWeekAgo)
        
        return ((dayAWeekago.day! - 1)..<day.day!)
    }
    
    var monthRange: ClosedRange<Int> {
        let month = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: future)
        let monthAWeekAgo = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: aWeekAgo)
        
        return ((monthAWeekAgo.month! - 7)...(month.month! - 7))
    }
}
```

// CardView //

```
struct CardView: View {
    
    var day: YearModel.MonthModel.DayModel
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(day.imageName)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6, alignment: .top)
            .border(Color(.sRGB, red: 150/255, green: 150/255, blue: 150/255, opacity: 0.1), width: 1)
            .overlay(
                VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 100)
                    .overlay(
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("\(day.date) - DAY \(day.id)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                
                                Text(day.whatILove)
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                    
                            }
                            .padding()
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    )
            }
                .foregroundColor(.white)

            )
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(colorScheme == .dark ? 0 : 0.3), radius: 15, y: 20)
    }
}
```

// YearModel.swift //

```
struct YearModel: Codable {
    let year: Int
    let months: [MonthModel]
    
    struct MonthModel: Codable {
        let monthName: String
        let dayInfo: [DayModel]
        
        struct DayModel: Codable {
            let whatILove: String
            let imageName: String
            let date: String
            let paragraph: String
            let id: Int
        }
    }
}
```

// JSON Decode file //

```
let yearData: [YearModel] = load("Data.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

// and Lastly, the JSON File I'm decoding for the information //

```
[
    {
        "year": 2020,
        "months": [
            {
                "monthName": "July",
                "dayInfo": [
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love You",
                        "imageName": "image1",
                        "date": "07/22/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": " I Love Your Laugh",
                        "imageName": "image2",
                        "date": "07/23/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Smile",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "07/24/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Kindness",
                        "imageName": "image4",
                        "date": "07/25/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": " I Love Your Nose",
                        "imageName": "image5",
                        "date": "07/26/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Who You Are",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "07/27/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 6
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Freckles",
                        "imageName": "image7",
                        "date": "07/28/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 7
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love That You Are Trustworthy",
                        "imageName": "image8",
                        "date": "07/29/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 8
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": " I Love Your Ears",
                        "imageName": "image9",
                        "date": "07/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 9
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "Happy 2 Years!",
                        "imageName": "image10",
                        "date": "07/31/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 10
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "monthName": "August",
                "dayInfo": [
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Music",
                        "imageName": "image11",
                        "date": "08/01/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love That You Are Trustworthy",
                        "imageName": "image12",
                        "date": "08/02/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Kisses",
                        "imageName": "image13",
                        "date": "08/03/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 13
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image14",
                        "date": "08/04/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image15",
                        "date": "08/05/2020",
                        "paragraph": "",
                        "id": 15
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image16",
                        "date": "08/06/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 16
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image17",
                        "date": "08/07/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 17
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image18",
                        "date": "08/08/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 18
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image19",
                        "date": "08/09/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 19
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image20",
                        "date": "08/10/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/11/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 21
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/12/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 22
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/13/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 23
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/14/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 24
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/15/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 25
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/16/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 26
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/17/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 27
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/18/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 28
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image4",
                        "date": "08/19/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 29
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image2",
                        "date": "08/20/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 30
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/21/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 31
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/22/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 32
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/23/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 33
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/24/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 34
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/25/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 35
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/26/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 36
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/27/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 37
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/28/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 38
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/29/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 39
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/31/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 41
                    }
                ]
                
            },
            {
                "monthName": "September",
                "dayInfo": [
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 42
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your...",
                        "imageName": "image3",
                        "date": "08/30/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 71
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "year": 2021,
        "months": [
            {
                "monthName": "January",
                "dayInfo": [
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Smile",
                        "imageName": "image1",
                        "date": "01/01/2021",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Laugh",
                        "imageName": "image2",
                        "date": "01/02/2021",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "monthName": "February",
                "dayInfo": [
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Music",
                        "imageName": "image4",
                        "date": "08/01/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "whatILove": "I Love Your Kiss",
                        "imageName": "image6",
                        "date": "08/02/2020",
                        "paragraph": "...",
                        "id": 12
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I realize it's a lot of code, but I hope that doesn't scare away people! Anyway though, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

Use An array of DateComponents to describe the last six days, including their month and their year. That way, you can let the DateComponents handle the work of dealing with a range that uses two months or even two years.

```swift
/// Calculates Dates for the last n days, starting with the previous day.
func lastNDays(n: Int) -> [Date]? {
        guard n > 0 else { return nil }
        var result = [Date]()
        for i in 1...n {
            guard let ithPreviousDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -i), to: Date()) else { 
                return nil 
            }
            result.append(ithPreviousDay)
        }
        return result
    }

var lastSixDaysAsDateComponents: [DateComponents] {
    guard let lastSixDays = lastNDays(n: 6) else { return [] }
    return lastSixDays.map{ day in 
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: day) 
    }
}
```

Then in your view body:

```swift
ForEach(self.lastSixDaysAsDateComponents, id: \.self) { dateComp in
    CardViewday: yearData[dateComp.year!].months[dateComp.month!].dayInfo[dateComp.day!])
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! So I tried implementing this, and it seems that I'm getting this error: Referencing instance method 'reversed()' on 'Range' requires that 'DayInMonth' conform to 'Strideable.' I tried removing the .reversed() to see if that would fix it, though it still gave me the same error! Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I have edited my answer and it now actually is closer to your original approach. Im wondering though why you always access months[0]. Is that intended?

Comment: Nope, that's not intended! That's one of the inputs that I've been trying to figure out how to add into it, same thing as the year! Using similar to what you did up there, I made one for months that returns an array of months, but I've realized I have no way of using it that I'm aware of yet, as I'd somehow need to use the dayInMonth! The reason I put that in the code is because otherwise it wouldn't run correctly, though I realize I should've probably mentioned those inputs more specifically! Any Ideas on how to do that?

Comment: In that case, i would build an array of 6 DateComponents, where each one represents one of the last 6 days. Pass that array to your view, and in ForEach, you can access date, month and year of each DateComponents struct. With that info, you can access your model with the three values. Maybe that works better?

Comment: Do you know how I would go about doing that?

Comment: See my edited answer. I didn't test it, so there might still be some issues.

Comment: You're good, thank you so much for your help! I ended up figuring everything out with the code you've provided, so thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Today i learned something about DateComponents :p